# Renaming an obscure file Java

Tags: java, file

Ok, so I have a folder with about 2000 pictures, all with weird names, I would like to loop through the whole thing, and rename them to "something" + the number(i in the for loop). Is there anyway to rename a file when you only know the place in the directory and not the name. I guess the main problem is getting the name of the file at index x in a directory, is there anyway to do this?

```
public class stuff {
  static ArrayList<File> images = new ArrayList<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Seth Gower\\Pictures\\Stuff for imgur\\iFunny Dumps\\iFunny Dump (All)"))
      .forEach(filePath -> {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
          images.add(new File(filePath.toString()));
        }
      });
    for(File x : images)
      System.out.println(x.getName());

    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i ++){
      System.out.println(images.get(i).renameTo(new File(
          "C:\\Users\\Seth Gower\\Pictures\\Stuff for imgur\\iFunny Dumps\\iFunny Dump (All)" + "\\" + "ifunnyDump" + i)));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is. What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried just adding all of the files to an ArrayList, renaming each of them, and then overwriting all of the existing ones in the folder with the renamed ones, but that is very inneficient

Comment: Have you considered sorting the ArrayList in the same sort order as your operating system file manager, and then simply renaming the nth file in that arraylist?

Comment: that is essentially the same thing, I just don't want to have to have to rewrite them after they are renamed in the ArrayList

Comment: I strongly recommend including your code in your post so that it is clearer exactly what you mean by overwriting in relation to your list. As it stands there is a fair amount of ambiguity in what we are both talking about.

Comment: I don't have the code on this computer, it is on the school computer, can you explain what you are talking about (sorry)

Comment: In a nutshell, if you want to rename the 153rd file in your folder, you would make the list of filenames, and sort them the way you want. You can then call `get(152)` on the list (since the indices are 0-based) to get the filename, and call the rename function on just that filename. Sorting a list isn't a terribly inefficient thing to do and is unavoidable if you want to find the nth filename in some sort order.

Comment: Ok, I just rewrote it, and this is what I had, but hadn't run it yet, just did, and it corrupted all of the images.... here is the code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zYWWjfqT

Comment: Has it really corrupted the files or just not put the extensions (.gif, .png, .jpg or whatever) on the new names?

Comment: I didn't think of that...I will run it again with extensions added

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!! thanks @MatthewStrawbridge, that was such a stupid mistake

Comment: and thank you @hexafraction, thank you for teaching me something new

Comment: Happy to hear that your issue has been resolved. @MatthewStrawbridge, will you be posting an answer to this regard?

Comment: @hexafraction Seth's answer looks reasonable so I recommend he just accept that and bag the points :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static ArrayList<File> images = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Files.walk(Paths.get("path")).forEach(filePath -> {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
            images.add(new File(filePath.toString()));
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i ++){
        images.get(i).renameTo(new File("path" + "\\" + "text" + i + ".jpg"));
    }


}
```

This worked, thanks to @hexafraction and @MatthewStrawbridge

Comment: Could be better, it could end up renaming png files to jpg.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient. It may work, but it is really bad practice to use up memory unnecessarily by looping through each file to once to add it to an arraylist, then looping through that arraylist to rename them when java has the ability to read/write file names natively.

Comment: @sbowde4 As example code, or one shot-code for a couple thousand files on a computer with gigabytes of RAM. It's fine. The author made no claims about memory efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple

you need to first find the directory your files are located in

```
File dir = new File("C:\\yourdirectory");
```

now you need to loop through every file in the directory an rename it. A for each loop would be best. If you want before the loop you can check if the directory you specified is really a directory with 
`if (dir.isDirectory())`

```
int i = 0;
for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
    try {
        f.renameTo("YourText_"+i+".jpg");
        i++;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: I just forgot to add it in, it's really simple to put it in yourself by doing `f.renameTo("YourText_"+i+".jpg");`

Comment: thank you, I only marked the other one as an answer because that is the one I used (since it is my own answer), but your's does seem good too.